# Resize Image to fit in bounding box

Tags: c#, algorithm, image-processing, image-manipulation

An easy problem, but for some reason I just can't figure this out today.

I need to resize an image to the maximum possible size that will fit in a bounding box while maintaining the aspect ratio.

Basicly I'm looking for the code to fill in this function:

```
void CalcNewDimensions(ref int w, ref int h, int MaxWidth, int MaxHeight);
```

Where w & h are the original height and width (in) and the new height and width (out) and MaxWidth and MaxHeight define the bounding box that the image must fit in.

Comment: Please don't abuse refs like that. Far better to make an _immutable_ struct Rectangle that has a width and a height field, and then write a method ExpandToBound that takes two Rectangles and returns the resulting Rectangle. It is much easier to reason about functions when you implement them as _functions_. Arguments go in, results come out; functions do not mutate state that they do not own.

Comment: @Eric Lippert - Agreed, the example wasn't the function I actually implemented, just a boiled-down version to avoid confusing the issue with Rectangle structs or other things that aren't part of the core of the problem.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Find which is smaller: `MaxWidth / w` or  `MaxHeight / h`
Then multiply `w` and `h` by that number

**Explanation:**

You need to find the scaling factor which makes the image fit.

To find the scaling factor, `s`, for the width, then `s` must be such that:
    `s * w = MaxWidth`.
Therefore, the scaling factor is `MaxWidth / w`.

Similarly for height.

The one that requires the most scaling (smaller `s`) is the factor by which you must scale the whole image.

Comment: If you do that with float you might probably find that the dimension which matches the bounding box is slightly off (sometimes, in an unpredictable way). When you've identified which dimension doesn't match, might it be best to simply assume the other one is exactly what it should be?

Comment: +1 Three years later sitting at the top of my Google results. No muss, no fuss. Thanks!

Comment: Like how your response isn't written in c, so I can apply it to python

Comment: Thank you for supplying an algorithm and explanation instead of just code! I wish more solutions were written like this.

Comment: Thanks, this works well. the explanation really helped too

Comment: What if the x,y of the image in the box can be anything not just 0,0?

Answer (score 28):

Based on Eric's suggestion I'd do something like this:

```
private static Size ExpandToBound(Size image, Size boundingBox)
{       
    double widthScale = 0, heightScale = 0;
    if (image.Width != 0)
        widthScale = (double)boundingBox.Width / (double)image.Width;
    if (image.Height != 0)
        heightScale = (double)boundingBox.Height / (double)image.Height;                

    double scale = Math.Min(widthScale, heightScale);

    Size result = new Size((int)(image.Width * scale), 
                        (int)(image.Height * scale));
    return result;
}
```

I might have gone a bit overboard on the casts, but I was just trying to preserve precision in the calculations.

Comment: don't forget to `return result;`

Answer (score 8):

To perform an aspect fill instead of an aspect fit, use the larger ratio instead. That is, change Matt's code from Math.Min to Math.Max.

(An aspect fill leaves none of the bounding box empty but may put some of the image outside the bounds, while an aspect fit leaves none of the image outside the bounds but may leave some of the bounding box empty.)

Comment: Excellent information. It wasn't intuitive to me looking at the other answers

Answer (score 7):

Tried Mr. Warren's code, but it didn't produce reliable results.

For example,

```
ExpandToBound(new Size(640,480), new Size(66, 999)).Dump();
// {Width=66, Height=49}

ExpandToBound(new Size(640,480), new Size(999,50)).Dump();
// {Width=66, Height=50}
```

You can see, height = 49 and height = 50 in another.

Here's mine (based version of Mr. Warren's code) without the discrepancy and a slight refactor:

```
// Passing null for either maxWidth or maxHeight maintains aspect ratio while
//        the other non-null parameter is guaranteed to be constrained to
//        its maximum value.
//
//  Example: maxHeight = 50, maxWidth = null
//    Constrain the height to a maximum value of 50, respecting the aspect
//    ratio, to any width.
//
//  Example: maxHeight = 100, maxWidth = 90
//    Constrain the height to a maximum of 100 and width to a maximum of 90
//    whichever comes first.
//
private static Size ScaleSize( Size from, int? maxWidth, int? maxHeight )
{
   if ( !maxWidth.HasValue && !maxHeight.HasValue ) throw new ArgumentException( "At least one scale factor (toWidth or toHeight) must not be null." );
   if ( from.Height == 0 || from.Width == 0 ) throw new ArgumentException( "Cannot scale size from zero." );

   double? widthScale = null;
   double? heightScale = null;

   if ( maxWidth.HasValue )
   {
       widthScale = maxWidth.Value / (double)from.Width;
   }
   if ( maxHeight.HasValue )
   {
       heightScale = maxHeight.Value / (double)from.Height;
   }

   double scale = Math.Min( (double)(widthScale ?? heightScale),
                            (double)(heightScale ?? widthScale) );

   return new Size( (int)Math.Floor( from.Width * scale ), (int)Math.Ceiling( from.Height * scale ) );
}
```

Comment: You shoud use Math.Round in both cases in the last line as in your code we get wrong results.

Answer (score 5):

Following code produces more accurate results:

```
    public static Size CalculateResizeToFit(Size imageSize, Size boxSize)
    {
        // TODO: Check for arguments (for null and <=0)
        var widthScale = boxSize.Width / (double)imageSize.Width;
        var heightScale = boxSize.Height / (double)imageSize.Height;
        var scale = Math.Min(widthScale, heightScale);
        return new Size(
            (int)Math.Round((imageSize.Width * scale)),
            (int)Math.Round((imageSize.Height * scale))
            );
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Python code, but maybe it will point you in the right direction:

```
def fit_within_box(box_width, box_height, width, height):
    """
    Returns a tuple (new_width, new_height) which has the property
    that it fits within box_width and box_height and has (close to)
    the same aspect ratio as the original size
    """
    new_width, new_height = width, height
    aspect_ratio = float(width) / float(height)

    if new_width > box_width:
        new_width = box_width
        new_height = int(new_width / aspect_ratio)

    if new_height > box_height:
        new_height = box_height
        new_width = int(new_height * aspect_ratio)

    return (new_width, new_height)
```

Comment: Your code works if the image must be shrinked, not if it must be expanded to fit the container. I think you should update your conditionals like this:
`if new_width > box_width or new_height < box_height:`
And:
`if new_height > box_height or new_width < box_width:`

Answer (score 3):

Über simple. :) The issue is to find a factor by which you need to multiply width and height. The solution is to try using one and if it doesn't fit, use the other. So...

```
private float ScaleFactor(Rectangle outer, Rectangle inner)
{
    float factor = (float)outer.Height / (float)inner.Height;
    if ((float)inner.Width * factor > outer.Width) // Switch!
        factor = (float)outer.Width / (float)inner.Width;
    return factor;
}
```

To fit picture (pctRect) to window (wndRect) call like this

```
float factor=ScaleFactor(wndRect, pctRect); // Outer, inner
RectangleF resultRect=new RectangleF(0,0,pctRect.Width*factor,pctRect.Height*Factor)
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the previous answers, here's a Javascript function:

```js
/**
* fitInBox
* Constrains a box (width x height) to fit in a containing box (maxWidth x maxHeight), preserving the aspect ratio
* @param width      width of the box to be resized
* @param height     height of the box to be resized
* @param maxWidth   width of the containing box
* @param maxHeight  height of the containing box
* @param expandable (Bool) if output size is bigger than input size, output is left unchanged (false) or expanded (true)
* @return           {width, height} of the resized box
*/
function fitInBox(width, height, maxWidth, maxHeight, expandable) {
    "use strict";

    var aspect = width / height,
        initWidth = width,
        initHeight = height;

    if (width > maxWidth || height < maxHeight) {
        width = maxWidth;
        height = Math.floor(width / aspect);
    }

    if (height > maxHeight || width < maxWidth) {
        height = maxHeight;
        width = Math.floor(height * aspect);
    }

    if (!!expandable === false && (width >= initWidth || height >= initHeight)) {
        width = initWidth;
        height = initHeight;
    }

    return {
        width: width,
        height: height
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Python code for this task based on Jason's answer with fix for upscaling and argument reorder for conventional argument passing with img.shape.

```
def fit_within_box(box_height, box_width, height, width):
    """
    Returns a tuple (new_width, new_height) which has the property
    that it fits within box_width and box_height and has (close to)
    the same aspect ratio as the original size
    """
    new_width, new_height = width, height
    aspect_ratio = float(width) / float(height)

    if new_width > box_width or new_height < box_height:
        new_width = box_width
        new_height = int(new_width / aspect_ratio)

    if new_height > box_height or new_width < box_width:
        new_height = box_height
        new_width = int(new_height * aspect_ratio)

    return new_height, new_width
```