# Resource interpeted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/pdf

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, mime-types

I receive this warning whenever I trigger a download of a PDF. There don't seem to be any negatives to the warning, but I would like to know why Google Chrome is notifying me of this. I have tried adding an explicit response header and content length, but to no avail.

```
export: function () {
    _stage.toDataURL(function (dataURL) {
        //POST the data because dataURL is too large to pass using a GET.
        $.post('../PlanView/GeneratePDF', { DataURL: dataURL }, function (imageURL) { location.href = imageURL; });
    });
}

[CompressionFilterAttribute]
public string GeneratePDF(string dataURL)
{
    dataURL = Regex.Replace(dataURL, "^data:image/(png|jpg);base64,", string.Empty);

    byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(dataURL);
    System.Drawing.Image image;
    using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length))
    {
        memoryStream.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
        image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(memoryStream, true);
    }

    Document document;
    float maxHeight;
    float maxWidth;
    if (image.Height > image.Width)
    {
        document = new Document(PageSize.A4);
        maxHeight = PageSize.A4.Height - (document.TopMargin + document.BottomMargin);
        maxWidth = PageSize.A4.Width - (document.LeftMargin + document.RightMargin);
    }
    else
    {
        document = new Document(PageSize.A4.Rotate());
        maxHeight = PageSize.A4.Width - (document.LeftMargin + document.RightMargin);
        maxWidth = PageSize.A4.Height - (document.TopMargin + document.BottomMargin);
    }

    using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, memoryStream);
        document.Open();
        iTextSharp.text.Image planViewImage = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(image, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);

        //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106339/resize-image-to-fit-in-bounding-box
        //Find the scaling factor by determining which is smaller: MaxWidth/w or MaxHeight/h, then multiply w and h by that number.
        float scale = (maxHeight / image.Height < maxWidth / image.Width) ? (maxHeight / image.Height) : (maxWidth / image.Width);
        planViewImage.ScalePercent(scale * 100);

        document.Add(planViewImage);
        document.Close();

        //Store the image in a buffer because its hard to download an image during POST.
        Session["PlanViewPDF"] = memoryStream.ToArray();
    }

    //Return URL to another MVC URL which can GET the image.
    return "../PlanView/ExportPDF";
}

[CompressionFilterAttribute]
public ActionResult ExportPDF()
{
    byte[] buffer = Session["PlanViewPDF"] as byte[];
    Response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", buffer.Length.ToString());

    return File(buffer, "application/pdf", string.Format("Plan View {0:yyyy-MM-dd_hh-mm-ss-tt}.pdf", DateTime.Now)); 
}
```

[image]

Comment: What is the extension of your file ? exampleName.pdf ?

Comment: Well, I have given it the name "Plan View DateTime.pdf" as seen in the return File of ExportPDF. iTextSharp is responsible for the creation of the PDF document, though, so perhaps iTextSharp is not doing something to represent the PDF document correctly to Google Chrome?