# How to show the whole picture within a tableLayoutControl

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have just started learning C# and Visual Studio trying to work both on books and  on sample code.

I am aware that tis is not a very brilliant question, but this is the problem that I am trying to solve. I have a windows form and I need to show an image in a Picture box contained in a tableLayoutPanel. The simple problem is that the images I have to load could have several sizes and a typical image is not completely shown within the allocated space: only the area that fits the container is shown, the rest of the image is cutted off. I have to show the image in its entirety, i do not have to resize it. I have already set the autosize property, but this does not seems to work.

Here some code in the form.cs

```
   string imageName = openFileDialog1.FileName;        // Get the image name

// Read the image

try
{
img = ( Bitmap) Image .FromFile(imageName);
}
catch
{
     MessageBox.Show("oooops" , Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon .Hand);
}
pictureBox1.Image = img;   // show the image
```

and then in the private void InitializeComponent() found in the form.designer.cs:

```
this.flowLayoutPanel1 = new System.Windows.Forms.FlowLayoutPanel();
 ...
this.pictureBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
...
this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.pictureBox1, 1, 1);
...
this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.pictureBox1, 1, 1);
...
this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 9.034863F));
this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 2.388038F));
this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 88.5771F));
this.tableLayoutPanel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(784, 762);
...
this.pictureBox1.SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize;
```

Have you any hint about how to show the whole image?

Even using slidbars would be ok, but notwhithstanding the fact that the container has autoscroll = true, nothing happens and the image is still truncated.

Thanks for any help

Comment: see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106339/resize-image-to-fit-in-bounding-box

Comment: I do not want the resize the image. I want to show the whole image without resizing it.

Comment: Set the picture box' SizeMode property to Zoom.

Answer (score 1):

The autoscroll property in the tableLayout control manage the scrolling of the whole table, including all the child controls. When the image is too big to fit within the picture control box, the autoscroll = yes property show slidebars allowing to slide all the content packed in the table layout control, not the individual image cell. Picture box does not have an autoscroll property, because autoscroll is, as far as I understand, a container's property; to slide the image in its own assigned space an intermediate container should be used, I guess.

My question was not a good question. It is rooted in my confusion about the containment hierarchy and relevant properties, more than in a genuine lack of knowledge or notions. Well, there is always room to improve ...