# How to achieve a web browser like pdf rendering in java?

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

Im currently trying to do a pdf writer application where end users can draw( lines / shapes or text) over a pdf file. I am using a pdfbox to display the pdf files to java swing components like jPanel. The problem with pdfbox is it is slow in terms of rendring the pdf file because it uses bufferedImage and then drawn to the jPanel. The file also has a bad resolution and I cant zoom in/out of the file.

I want to achieve a web browser like display for my pdf files.

Thankyou.

Code for converting pdf to bufferedImage using pdfbox.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.ImageType;
import org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PDFRenderer;

public class Parse {

    private static File file;
    private int imageWidth;
    private int imageHeight;

    public Parse(File file) {
       this.file = file;
    }

    public BufferedImage getPage(int pageIndex) throws IOException {

       PDDocument pdf = PDDocument.load(file);  

       Float realWidth = new Float(pdf.getPage(0).getMediaBox().getWidth());
       Float realHeight = new 
       Float(pdf.getPage(0).getMediaBox().getHeight());

       Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
       Double ratio = .8;

       imageHeight = (int) (screenSize.getHeight() * ratio);
       imageWidth = (int) ((imageHeight * realWidth) / realHeight);

       PDFRenderer renderer = new PDFRenderer(pdf);

       BufferedImage renderImage = renderer.renderImage(pageIndex, 1, ImageType.RGB);
       pdf.close();
       return renderImage;
    }

    public int getImageWidth() {
       return imageWidth;
    }

    public void setImageWidth(int imageWidth) {
       this.imageWidth = imageWidth;
    }

    public int getImageHeight() {
       return imageHeight;
    }

    public void setImageHeight(int imageHeight) {
     this.imageHeight = imageHeight;
    }

}
```

Code for drawing the image to the JPanel.

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class PDFPanel extends JPanel {

    private Image image;
    private int width;
    private int height;

    public PDFPanel(Image image, int width, int height) {
        this.image = image;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;

        setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0, 0, 0, 0));
        setSize(width, height);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics graphics) {
        super.paintComponent(graphics);
        Graphics2D graphics2D = (Graphics2D) graphics;
        graphics2D.drawImage(image, 0, 0, width, height, null);
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi John, please add details to your question, see [ask].

Comment: Sorry please help me ..

Comment: Did you look at the javadoc of renderImage?

Comment: yes but I didn't understand , sorry I'm just new to programming
can you give me a sample code in rendering pdf to jpanel to help me more understand.

Comment: Can someone help me,
I think there is something wrong in my code....

Comment: I do have some code that renders to a JPanel (but will still be slow) but that wasn't your question, you also wanted to draw lines. The second parameter of renderImage is the scale.

Comment: yes please
actually sir I was the one who sent you an email..

Help

If recieved it.

Comment: Can someone help me to render in a pdf file in jPanel.
make it zoom in/out just like in a web browser

Comment: I did not receive mail from you. I have now shown something simple as an answer, but it doesn't zoom in/out. I can remove it if it isn't what you needed.

Comment: Thank you.
It is in deed slow .
I already have a code for displaying pdf but my problem now is cant zoom in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some code to display a PDF in a JPanel with PDFBox 2.0, based on code submitted in issue [PDFBOX-3359](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-3359). It doesn't zoom but it can change sizes. It will still be slow, and even slower the bigger the window gets.

```
public class PDFBox3359PanelTestEnhanced
{

    private static JPanel getTestPanel()
    {
        final PDDocument doc;
        try
        {
            doc = PDDocument.load(new File("XXXXX.pdf"));   

        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        final PDFRenderer renderer = new PDFRenderer(doc);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel()
        {
            int i;

            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
            {
                try
                {
                    g.setColor(Color.red);
                    g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
                    PDPage page = doc.getPage(0);
                    PDRectangle cropBox = page.getCropBox();
                    boolean rot = false;
                    if (page.getRotation() == 90 || page.getRotation() == 270)
                    {
                        rot = true;
                    }

                    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106339/resize-image-to-fit-in-bounding-box
                    float imgWidth = rot ? cropBox.getHeight() : cropBox.getWidth();
                    float imgHeight = rot ? cropBox.getWidth() : cropBox.getHeight();
                    float xf = getWidth() / imgWidth;
                    float yf = getHeight() / imgHeight;
                    float scale = Math.min(xf, yf);
                    if (yf < xf)
                    {
                        g.translate((int) ((getWidth() - imgWidth * yf) / 2), 0);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        g.translate(0, (int) ((getHeight() - imgHeight * xf) / 2));
                    }
                    renderer.renderPageToGraphics(0, (Graphics2D) g, scale);
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        return panel;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(getTestPanel());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setSize(600, 400);
                Dimension paneSize = frame.getSize();
                Dimension screenSize = frame.getToolkit().getScreenSize();
                frame.setLocation((screenSize.width - paneSize.width) / 2, (screenSize.height - paneSize.height) / 2);
                frame.setTitle("Test");
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```